# How can I take backup of specific tables in SQL Server using BCP

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to get backup from specifying multi-tables. I use this blow code(using bcp) :

```
DECLARE @table varchar(128),
        @file varchar(255),
        @cmd varchar(512)

SET @table = 'sas.Accounts' --  Table Name
SET @file = 'C:\Db_BackUps\ErpAccounting_' + @table + '_'+ CONVERT(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '.csv'
SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @table + ' out ' + @file + ' -T -w '

EXEC master..Xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

but I can't get all exist data in tables and BCP not copying all rows. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that would not copy all rows. How do you know it didn't copy all rows? How are you checking the file? Don't use Excel

Comment: I get the count of the target table and it was 30000, but when I get back up using this code the number of rows was 130.

Comment: You mean when you restore it back in? There’s no sample code provided for how you are doing that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when I open CSV file in excel that is lower than the real count of data in the table.

Comment: @user3194835, I suggest you use native mode (-n switch) instead of character mode (-w switch). This will be faster and avoid problems due to delimiters in the data.

Comment: Like I said don’t open it in Excel. Open it in notepad or VS Code

Comment: I also suggest you add a database name to your query to guarantee that you know the actual source of the rows (in case you have multiple databases with the same table/view).